# is DatagramSocket.send thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, datagram

I'm planning to use an instance of `DatagramSocket` and call its [send](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#send%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29) method from different threads... to send UDP packets to different clients. Is the method thread safe i.e. calling this method from different threads will not create any trouble/inconsistency/race condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UDP guarantees that datagrams arrive intact (if at all). In other words there can be no interleaving even if there is multithreading at the sender. That's all you need. You don't actually need thread safety. However the C send() system call is thread safe, like all system calls, because they are atomic.

Comment: But is it really guarantees that java wrapper will be thread safe? I think - no.

Comment: @turbanoff It's irrelevant whether the wrapper is thread-safe or not, as it isn't specified to change any state in any objects.

Comment: I don't get your argument. For example, SimpleDateFormat isn't specified to changed any state in any objects. But everybody know - it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @turbanoff So it changes state in itself. Otherwise it would be threadsafe. By definition.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. This is only a thin layer on the native OS, which is threadsafe.

See here http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t150685-is-datagramsocket-thread-safe.html

Comment: I saw this, but this lacks references!

Comment: Exactly. That's just a copy of a Sun Java forums thread, which I contributed to, from 2006. Not a normative reference.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, the layer on the native operating system is thread safe.

**BUT**, because network throughput is limited, if you send more packets than the network can handle, some packets will be dropped.

Comment: So......... is it threadsafe or not? There are contradicting answers in this very answer section.

Comment: Yes, it is thread safe. However, because network throughput is limited, if you send more packets than the network can handle, some packets will be dropped. But that has nothing to do with multithreading. Well, not directly.