# Recomended to send packets from same DatagramSocket from multiple classes?

Tags: java, network-programming, client-server

I'm creating a Server-Client networking library for java. I'm just wondering if it's recomended to use the same `DatagramSocket` object from multiple classes, or if it may cause problems.
The reason to why *I'm* wondering is because *I think* that it might be problems if you for example send two things at the same time from the same socket. Is that true?
Here is an example of what I mean:
*ExampleClass1:*

```
public class ExampleClass1 {

    // The socket
    DatagramSocket socket;

    public ExampleClass1() {
        // Create the socket
        socket = new DatagramSocket(1111);

        // Create an instance of the ExampleClass2
        ExampleClass2 class2 = new ExampleClass2(socket);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Send something through the socket
        socket.send(new DatagramPacket(new byte[] {}, 0, 0.0.0.0, 0001));
    }
}
```

*ExampleClass2:*

```
public class ExampleClass2 {

    // Another socket object
    DatagramSocket socket;

    public ExampleClass2(DatagramSocket exampleClass1Socket) {
        // Set this class's socket object to the socket in the ExampleClass1
        this.socket = exampleClass1Socket;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Send something from the socket
        socket.send(new DatagramSocket(new byte[] {}, 0, 0.0.0.0, 0000));
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498223/is-datagramsocket-send-thread-safe the send system call is atomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't true. You can send from multiple threads simultaneously with no problems.